# C++ member function masking external function - how to call external function?

Tags: c++

In a Qt application, I'm trying to call the networking function connect() (which is from sys/socket.h). The call's being made from a QObject object, which has its own connect() member function. The QObject's connect() method is preventing me from calling the networking connect() function.

Any way to use the networking connect()?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> C++ member function masking external function - how to call external function?

Use

```
::connect()
```

Comment: It's good practice to use this syntax for all calls to global scope.